# Configure xfce to use an alternative to the xdg-open program

Tags: xfce, xdg-open

I wonder how I would change the default file open application in xfce. In the terminal I always use `rifle` (from the terminal file manager `ranger`) and I would like to use `rifle` as well for when I open files using Firefox or Thunar.

How would I change the 'file opener' in xfce? Or is the only option just to symlink `/usr/bin/xdg-open` to `rifle`?

Comment: Could you not edit `~/.config/mimeapps.list` so xdg-open selects the applications that you prefer? Also, I have Debian 10 with Xfce. I have both exo-open `exo-utils` and xdg-open `xdg-utils`. I am not quite sure what role each has in the system.

Comment: It's the configuration of xdg-open that I want to prevent. It's quite confusing all. Now we also have exo-open...